# Normalizing softmax by dividing by its maximum?

Tags: softmax, graph-neural-network

Reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.13586), I'm struggling to understand the step with the question mark (page 3). The formula for $\textbf r$ uses $\textbf q_i$ (no tilde), but the numeric values in the following paragraph are in fact $\tilde{\textbf q}_a, \tilde{\textbf q}_b$ - the standard softmax formula, without division by $max_i \tilde{\textbf q_i} + \epsilon$.

I'm new to this... is this step some sort of numerical stability thing which has not played a role in this example? What am I not seeing here?

Thank you!

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing, the text seems to miss explanation. The important takeaway is how do use Fuzzy logic  where embedding values are nearly same for two classes.

The example discussed:

- h1 =[-1.2,2.3]
- q~ = [.0293,.9797]
- q =[.03,.99]  (assuming e =.001)

Apply threshold (0.5)

- r =[0,1]

Fuzzy encoding will be helpful when all classes have value below threshold.  For eg:

- h =[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
- q~ = [.1,.1,.1,.1,.1,.1,.1,.1,.1,.1]
- q = [.99,.99,.99,.99,.99,.99,.99,.99,.99,.99]
- r = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

Fuzzy encoding ensures that all classes with similar embedding value get same class.

- h = [1.2,1.3]
- q~ = [.475,.525]
- q = [.9,.99]
- r =[1,1]